# Error Emulador Xamarin Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Hola a todos quisiera que me puedan ayudar tengo un dispositivo con android 5.1 pero cuando lo pongo modo desarrollador y modo depuracion en el Visual studio no lo reconoce mi diapositivo como emulador . quisiera que me puedn ayudar por favor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema que me daba con el emulador era que no tenia el Hyper-V activado, que es lo que me proporciona la característica de poder virtualizar otros dispositivos en mi maquina, aquí le dejo el link de como activarlo en caso de que le de el mismo error que a mi.
[Install Hyper-V on Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v)

Comment: según lo que veo, NO está habilitado como desarrollador. Revisa: https://www.androidcentral.com/android-50-lollipop-basics-how-turn-developer-settings